How to make dynamic Select Box
I have a table in MySQL labour with row code, name, dept
code name    dept
1    john    electrical
2    edison  electrical
3    harman  housekeeping
If I want to update john from electrical to housekeeping via selectbox
a. 1st it should reflect selected value to electrical and then I should be able to select new value housekeeping and submit it to save
here is ths snippet code I worked on
  value=  >    ";  ?>
here is ths snippet code I worked on
  value=  >    ";  ?>
enter image description here
